# Code editor error: cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null

Tags: javascript, adobe-brackets

As you can check the following code is running fine in here but when I am running this on "Brackets" (code editor), it gives me this error:

"cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null..."

And as a result the code doesn't work.

Is there something wrong in the syntax or is it something to do with the code editor?

Thanks.

```js
var dropBtn = document.getElementById('dropdown-btn');

dropBtn.addEventListener('click',function() {
    var dropContent = document.querySelector('.dropdown-content');
    dropContent.classList.toggle('show');
});
```

```css
#dropdown-btn {
  background-color:orange;
  display:inline-block;
  padding:5px;
  color:white;
  cursor:pointer;
}
.dropdown-content {
  display:none;
}
.show {
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<div id="dropdown-btn">Button</div>

<div class="dropdown-content">
  <div>link1</div>
  <div>link1</div>
  <div>link1</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Where is the Javascript located relative to the HTML? If the JS is before the HTML, then the DOM element doesn't exist yet when you assign the variable.

Comment: @Barmar Yeah thanks. That was the issue. I had the JS before the HTML.